# Tomee stateless bean pool size setting

Tags: apache-tomee, tomee-7

According to http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html for stateless beans the max poolsize can be set as a property within

```html
<Container id="Foo" type="STATELESS">
</Container>
```

I need to know how ID attribute is related to the server instance. Can I use any name instead of "Foo"? If not, where do I declare Foo?

Answer (score 0):

Id is really the name of the container. You can define multiple and bind a container to an EJB through openejb-jar.xml if desired but if there is only one it is the global container for all EJB.

Value is not important.